# If a function is passed as an argument to another function, is the first function's name accessible?

Tags: functions, symbols

I have some code that takes as an argument a function:

```
(defun message-name (fn)
  )
```

I would like to be able to, if the function has a name, message it. For example, if called this way:

```
(message-name #'get-buffer)
```

I would like this code to message `The function's name is get-buffer`:

```
(defun message-name (fn)
  (message "The function's name is %s."
           (????? fn)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are passing a *symbol* (as in your example) then yes, you can get the `symbol-name` of the argument. e.g.:

```
(symbol-name fn)
```

A "function passed as an argument" might also be a function object, though, and you can't pull a symbol name from that. You would have to search for a symbol which had the same value in its function cell.

Comment: Small addition: you may want to check if `fn` is a symbol first with `symbolp`, as `symbol-name` will throw an error if `fn` is not a symbol.

Comment: To be quite clear, a function argument that is not a symbol (what you call a "function object") may not even _have_ a name. Then searching for the symbol that had the same value in its function cell would be fruitless.